# Standard error of a sum of two Poisson variables

Tags: poisson-distribution, standard-error

I have 2 Poisson variables, I know mean and standard error for each. How do you calculate the Standard error of the sum?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched elsewhere on this site to try to find an answer? Also, if this is for homework or self-study, you should add the `self-study` tag. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the term standard error refers to the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of a statistic, e. g. the sampling mean as an estimator for the expectation. In situations where one is not dealing with an estimator but with a random variable on its own, one talks about standard deviation instead of standard error.

The standard deviation $SD$ of a random variable $X$ is defined as $SD=\sqrt{Var[X]}$. This is equivalent in saying $SD^2=Var[X]$. Moreover, the variance of the sum of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is defined as $Var[X+Y]=Var[X]+Var[Y]+2Cov[X,Y]$. Please note, in case $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the last term is equal to zero. In case $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, the covariance is defined as $Cov[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$.

Thus, you need to compute $SD[X+Y]=\sqrt{Var[X+Y]}=\sqrt{ Var[X]+Var[Y]+2Cov[X,Y]}$.

Comment: I had this information for Variance. But i have standard error (no variance). How to compute the standard error of X+Y

Comment: I edited my answer, so please have look on it.

Comment: This is standard  dev not standard er